# More efficient way to reorder pandas columns and perform calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   | cat1 - Sept | cat2 - Sept | cat3 - Sept | cat4 - Sept | cat1 - Aug | cat2 - Aug | cat3 - Aug | cat4 - Aug |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 0 |          49 |           6 |          35 |          24 |         15 |         10 |         45 |         37 |
| 1 |           4 |           2 |          32 |          20 |         21 |         26 |         43 |         41 |
| 2 |           3 |          42 |          22 |           8 |         15 |         17 |         45 |          3 |
| 3 |           3 |           5 |          32 |          14 |         28 |         11 |         45 |          3 |
| 4 |           4 |          22 |           9 |          50 |          1 |          8 |         16 |         23 |
| 5 |          10 |          15 |           9 |          41 |          3 |         35 |         30 |         34 |
| 6 |          21 |           4 |          12 |          44 |         43 |         32 |         12 |         10 |
| 7 |           4 |          49 |          42 |          30 |         11 |         25 |         27 |         24 |
| 8 |          46 |          18 |          46 |          29 |         36 |          5 |         46 |         23 |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

In reality, each of the months has 15 categories.  What I would like to do is transform the data frame to this:

```
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|   | cat1 - Sept | % Change | cat2 - Sept | % Change | cat3 - Sept | % Change | cat4 - Sept | % Change |
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| 0 |          49 | 227%     |           6 | -40%     |          35 | -22%     |          24 | -35%     |
| 1 |           4 | -81%     |           2 | -92%     |          32 | -26%     |          20 | -51%     |
| 2 |           3 | -80%     |          42 | 147%     |          22 | -51%     |           8 | 167%     |
| 3 |           3 | -89%     |           5 | -55%     |          32 | -29%     |          14 | 367%     |
| 4 |           4 | 300%     |          22 | 175%     |           9 | -44%     |          50 | 117%     |
| 5 |          10 | 233%     |          15 | -57%     |           9 | -70%     |          41 | 21%      |
| 6 |          21 | -51%     |           4 | -88%     |          12 | 0%       |          44 | 340%     |
| 7 |           4 | -64%     |          49 | 96%      |          42 | 56%      |          30 | 25%      |
| 8 |          46 | 28%      |          18 | 260%     |          46 | 0%       |          29 | 26%      |
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

This really easy to do, but it requires a lot of code and is very manual:

- Reorder the columns so each category is next to its respective month
- Create new column for all categories to calculate percent change
- Delete august columns

I'm looking for a particular pandas function or idiom for column organization to cut down the code and make this more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way would be to using a `MultiIndex` column.

```
In [102]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [222]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(b,a) for (a,b) in df.columns.str.split(' - ')])

In [223]: df = df.sortlevel(level=(0,1), axis=1)

In [224]: new_cols = [('% Change', cat) for cat in df.columns.levels[1]]

In [225]: df[new_cols] = df['Sept'] / df['Aug'] - 1

In [226]: df = df.loc[:, idx[['Sept', '% Change'], :]]

In [227]: df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)

In [228]: df = df.sortlevel(level=(0,1), axis=1)

In [229]: df
Out[229]: 
  cat1           cat2           cat3           cat4          
  Sept  % Change Sept  % Change Sept  % Change Sept  % Change
0   49  2.266667    6 -0.400000   35 -0.222222   24 -0.351351
1    4 -0.809524    2 -0.923077   32 -0.255814   20 -0.512195
2    3 -0.800000   42  1.470588   22 -0.511111    8  1.666667
3    3 -0.892857    5 -0.545455   32 -0.288889   14  3.666667
4    4  3.000000   22  1.750000    9 -0.437500   50  1.173913
5   10  2.333333   15 -0.571429    9 -0.700000   41  0.205882
6   21 -0.511628    4 -0.875000   12  0.000000   44  3.400000
7    4 -0.636364   49  0.960000   42  0.555556   30  0.250000
8   46  0.277778   18  2.600000   46  0.000000   29  0.260870
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm getting this error `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'` here `df = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Sept']]`. thoughts?

Comment: Oops, need to sort after assigning the `MultiIndex` too, edited above.

Comment: Thoughts on this error?     `df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=(0,1))
TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'`  Docs clearly show that level is a kw arg.  Idk why it's unexpected.

Comment: I think that keyword may have been added in version `0.17`? If you're on older version you could do `df.sortlevel`

Comment: hey, so i just noticed that the percent change columns are wrong.  the percent change columns in my second table are accurate, but yours don't seem to match.  i tried it with my real dataset and the numbers seem incorrect also.  thoughts on which step this is happening at? it looks like stuff might be getting shifted downwards because there are NaNs at the 0 index

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, `pct_change` calculates the row-over-row change.  I've edited my answer to match what you want.